# Get value of a merged cell of an excel from its cell address in vba

Tags: excel, vba, merge, cell

How to get the value of a merged cell of an excel having range address like "$B$4:$B$11" in vba

Comment: Excel, I assume? Worth adding as a tag...

Comment: `Range("B4:B11").Cells(1).Value` ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Even if it is really discouraged to use merge cells in Excel (use [`Center Across Selection`](http://thenewpaperclip.com/2008/04/15/center-across-selection-the-merge-and-center-alternative-in-excel-2007/) for instance if needed), the cell that "contains" the value is the one on the **top left** (at least, that's a way to express it).

Hence, you can get the value of merged cells in range `B4:B11` in several ways:

- `Range("B4").Value`
- `Range("B4:B11").Cells(1).Value`
- `Range("B4:B11").Cells(1,1).Value`

You can also note that all the other cells have no value in them. While debugging, you can see that the value is `empty`.

Also note that `Range("B4:B11").Value` won't work (raises an execution error number 13 if you try to `Debug.Print` it) because it returns an array.

Comment: When I don't know the bounds of the merged area, I get the value with `Range("B6").MergeArea.Cells(1,1).Value`

Comment: Nice tip! <!--5 more to go...-->

Comment: Also: `Range("B4:B11").Item(1).Value` , or simply, `Range("B4:B11")(1).Value`

Answer (score 42):

Josh Brown gave (in a comment) what I think is the best answer:

When I don't know the bounds of the merged area, I get the value with

```
Range("B6").MergeArea.Cells(1,1).Value
```

This is helpful in VBA when, for example, you are looping through files that might have merged cells of unknown ranges, so you can be much more general with this method. Thanks Josh!

Answer (score -1):

This can be done in 2 steps:

First name the range of the merged cells; highlight the merged cell then go on the Ribbon Bar: `Formulas Tab --> Define Name;`

Make sure there are no spaces in the name. Example: `defined_Name`. Go to the desired cell you wish to see the output/result. In that cell, type: `=defined_Name`.

Press enter because your done.

Comment: This does not pertain to VBA.  Also, using VBA you might have no idea where the merged cell is or what it's bounds are.

Answer (score -1):

(Excel 2016)

I am hoping this will help somebody.

I have found that if you press delete on a merged cell,
the target.cells.count = the number of merged cells.

Whereas if you change the value on the same cell, the target.cells.count = 1

This caused me issues as I was skipping multi selections in my worksheet_change code by testing the number of cells selected.