# Excel - Why is Naming a Merged Range different from Merging a Range and then Naming it?

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

I know, I know, merged ranges are horrible to work with. But anyway:

I discovered some funny behaviour, whereby I could copy/paste some Merged Ranges but not others. So I experimented.

Setup:

[image]

[image]

Already it's apparent that these ranges are not the same thing. The ranges that were named after they were merged only consist of the topLeftCell reference, whereas the ones merged after naming retain a reference to all cells.

---

Edit: Test Code

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PerformTests()

    Const NAME_THEN_MERGE As String = "Name_Then_Merge"
    Const MERGE_THEN_NAME As String = "Merge_Then_Name"
    Const PASTE_NAME_THEN_MERGE As String = "Paste_Name_Then_Merge"
    Const PASTE_MERGE_THEN_NAME As String = "Paste_Merge_Then_Name"

    TestNames MERGE_THEN_NAME, PASTE_NAME_THEN_MERGE
    '/ Result: Error 1004, cannot do that to a merged cell


End Sub

Public Sub TestNames(ByVal copyName As String, ByVal pasteName As String)

    wsPasteTest.Activate

    Dim copyRange As Range, pasteRange As Range
    Set copyRange = wsPasteTest.Range(copyName)
    Set pasteRange = wsPasteTest.Range(pasteName)

    CopyPasteCell copyRange, pasteRange

End Sub

Public Sub CopyPasteCell(ByRef copyCell As Range, ByRef pasteCell As Range, Optional ByVal pasteRowHeights As Boolean = False)

    copyCell.Copy
    pasteCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

    If pasteRowHeights Then
        Dim sourceRowHeight As Long
        sourceRowHeight = copyCell.rowHeight
        pasteCell.rowHeight = sourceRowHeight
    End If

End Sub
```

---

After extensive testing, this appears to be the conclusion:

If you name a range of cells and then merge them, the named Range retains a reference to all of the cells. If you merge first, the named range only refers to the topLeftCell.

If you try to copy a named range, it is treated as being the same size as its' reference. So, it is fine to copy a (named then merged) set of 5 cells to another set of merged cells of the same size, or to a single cell.

However, the (merged then named) range can only be copied to a single cell. Trying to copy to a set of 5 merged cells will result in a 1004 error.

---

Why? What is going on with how merged cells and named ranges are handled that causes this discrepancy?

---

For reference, this is Office 365, Excel Version 15.0.4805.1003

Comment: I blame [Joel](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky).

Comment: What is the paste method when you are getting the 1004 error? I'm having trouble replicating the error

Comment: @Dan added the test code

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to take a stab at this as I think I've tested enough with your code to understand what's going on.

Let's start with how Excel is handling the various named ranges when performing the actions you have designated. You can see that after setting `copyRange` to the `MERGE_THEN_NAME` constant, and using `.Copy` (for testing purposes) on the newly defined `copyRange`, the `A2` cell is has the moving dashed lines around it.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PerformTests()

    Const NAME_THEN_MERGE As String = "Name_Then_Merge"
    Const MERGE_THEN_NAME As String = "Merge_Then_Name"
    Const PASTE_NAME_THEN_MERGE As String = "Paste_Name_Then_Merge"
    Const PASTE_MERGE_THEN_NAME As String = "Paste_Merge_Then_Name"

    TestNames MERGE_THEN_NAME, PASTE_MERGE_THEN_NAME
    '/ Result: Error 1004, cannot do that to a merged cell


End Sub

Public Sub TestNames(ByVal copyName As String, ByVal pasteName As String)

    Sheets("wsPasteTest").Activate

    Dim copyRange As Range, pasteRange As Range
    Set copyRange = Sheets("wsPasteTest").Range(copyName)
    copyRange.Copy    'This is the last step executed before error
    Set pasteRange = Sheets("wsPasteTest").Range(pasteName)

    CopyPasteCell copyRange, pasteRange

End Sub
```

[image]

This is expected since the defined range is read as `=wsPasteTest!$A$2` in the Name Manager.

[image: Name Manager Description]

This definition of the range means that when Excel revisits the named range to extract a value, it does so by interpreting the address literally, i.e. it only considers the cell value of A2 since [the merged cells' value is defined in the "top left"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9408817/3657636) cell address of itself. This logic can be confirmed by the correct method of returning the value of a merged cell through VBA procedures (which is addressed in the above hyperlink) by needing to use something like `Range("A2:E2").Cells(1).Value` rather than simply `Range("A2:E2").Value`. The latter option returns an array because it is considering each individual cell's value in the range.

---

The next part here is why it can be dangerous to use `.Select` or `.Activate` through your whole code, but also shows how to get the behavior you would like. We can see when we `.Select` the `copyCell` that it selects the whole merged cell compared to just `A2` in the `.Copy` method (which mimics how a user interacts with the range on the spreadsheet itself). So now, if we select `copyCell` and then use `Selection.Copy`, the whole merged cell is copied rather than just `A2` since Excel has been instructed to grab the whole array area. Excel has also just shown how significant selecting an item and then using the selection can drastically change its interpretation of a range rather than explicitly working with the range.

The code in `PerformTests()` and `TestNames()` is identical to yours, the following sub was modified:

```
Public Sub CopyPasteCell(ByRef copyCell As Range, ByRef pasteCell As Range, Optional ByVal pasteRowHeights As Boolean = False)

    copyCell.Select
    Selection.Copy 'this step is shown in the first screenshot below
    pasteCell.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 'this step is shown in the second screentshot below

    If pasteRowHeights Then
        Dim sourceRowHeight As Long
        sourceRowHeight = copyCell.RowHeight
        pasteCell.RowHeight = sourceRowHeight
    End If

End Sub
```

Here's the result of the `copyCell` being selected, then copied.

[image: Selection.Copy result]

Here's the result of the `pasteCell` being selected, then pasted into. This shows the result you desired while using `Merge_Then_Name` range.

[image: selection.PastSpecial result]

---

Ultimately, you can see that when you refer to a named range explicitly that has been defined **after** merging, it interprets the named range's address literally (giving a single cell value with single cell formatting) which clearly cannot be pasted into the area size desired using the pasting method suggested. **If you change your pasting method to `xlPasteValues` you can avoid using `.Select`**. The reason for this is because it allows the definition of `Paste_Merge_Then_Name` to remain as `=wsPasteTest!$A$8` while also allowing for the value to be transferred to a single cell area. This method keeps the destination cell's formatting the same while just replacing the value. It is not exactly what your intended paste was, but quite close.

```
Public Sub CopyPasteCell(ByRef copyCell As Range, ByRef pasteCell As Range, Optional ByVal pasteRowHeights As Boolean = False)

    copyCell.Copy
    pasteCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    If pasteRowHeights Then
        Dim sourceRowHeight As Long
        sourceRowHeight = copyCell.RowHeight
        pasteCell.RowHeight = sourceRowHeight
    End If

End Sub
```

[image: PasteSpecial Result]

---

The `Name_Then_Merge` range works with both single cell and the named range pastes for one main reason; how many placeholders it contains for values. When you do the `.Copy` method of `Name_Then_Merge`, it selects the whole merged cell **because it's instructed to by its definition** `=wsPasteTest!$A$5:$E$5`. This is good because pasting this into an equal sized named range would work because they match, and pasting into a single cell would work because there's a single non-blank value.

---

Summary: The named ranges are defined by their initial cell values and hold that number of "places" even after cells are merged. So if you name a range, it references the values of the each cell in a range (5 values in this case), and merging the cell does not change the definition of the named range (but changes all values of the array after the first cell to "" as a placeholder). If you merge cells and then name the range, the value is held in the top left cell of the merged area, and is therefore used as the definition of the merged cell for the named range. In this case, Excel gets confused if you try to just `.Paste` or `xlPasteAll` this into a merged cell because it'll copy the value of the source as a single cell area and attempt to paste it into the destination which is a five cell area.

Solve this by making sure to copy the whole area of the named range by selecting it or by using a different paste method **but be wary of what these paste methods produce**. E.g. `xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme` will unmerge the destination cells but still satisfies the named range definition.