# Excel VBA problems with combined cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a Excel VBA program to generate text.
I am using IF statements to find out if some specific text is in in a cell and concatenate a string based on that.

I have a problem with combined cells:

[image]

```
IF Cells(1,1) Like "A" and Cells(1,2) Like "---" Then
concatenate something
end if
```

The above works

```
IF Cells(2,1) Like "B" and Cells(2,2) Like "---" Then
concatenate something
end if
```

This does not work, because the Cell(2,2) is empty according to
MsgBox (Cells(2, 2).Value) instead of the "---".

Is it possible to get the code to work, without splitting the cells again?

I would like to go row by row concatenating text, the VBA code should recognize the cellvalue one cell right to "B" as "---".

Comment: To get value of the "Merged" cells, they need to referenced with the first cell address amongst them. So, When cells `Cells(1,2)` ; `Cells(2,2)` and `Cells(3,2)` are merged then value in them could be taken using `Cells(1,2)` and not `Cells(2,2)` or `Cells(3,2)` as they lost their identity after merging with `Cells(1,2)`

Comment: DUPLICATE Question..  Use `Range("B3").MergeArea.Cells(1,1).Value` ... Refer comments on [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9408817/9808063)

Answer (score 2):

`Cells(1,1).Value` is "A".  `Cells(1,2).Value` is "---".
`Cells(2,1).Value` is empty.  `Cells(3,2).Value` is empty.
`Cells(3,1).Value` is "B".  `Cells(3,2).Value` is empty.

Just because you merge the cells above, doesn't change that the cell is in Row 3.  Only the top-left cell in a Merged Range has a value.  (Although, there *are* [ways around that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49816515/excel-filtering-for-merged-cells/49817670#49817670).)

You can check if a cell is merged [using `Range.MergeCells`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.mergecells).  You can get the value of a Merged Cell [using `Range.MergeArea`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.mergearea)

For example:
`Cells(1,1).MergeArea.Cells(1,1)` is "A".  `Cells(2,2).MergeArea.Cells(1,1)` is "---".  `Cells(1,1).MergeCells` is `True`.
`Cells(2,1).MergeArea.Cells(1,1)` is "A".  `Cells(2,2).MergeArea.Cells(1,1)` is "---".  `Cells(2,1).MergeCells` is `True`.
`Cells(3,1).MergeArea.Cells(1,1)` is "B".  `Cells(3,2).MergeArea.Cells(1,1)` is "---".  `Cells(3,1).MergeCells` is `False`.

If you are using a loop to run through the cells, consider using a `While` or `Do` instead of a `For`, since you can increment by different numbers for each iteration:

```
Dim rowCurrent AS Long
rowCurrent = 1
While Cells(rowCurrent,1).Value <> ""
    If Cells(rowCurrent,2).MergeArea.Cells(1,1).Value = "---" Then
        Select Case Cells(rowCurrent,1).MergeArea.Cells(1,1).Value
            Case "A"
                'concatenate something
            Case "B"
                'concatenate something else
            Case "C"
                'concatenate a third thing
            Case Else
                'throw an error?
        End Select
    End If
    'Skip the rest of the merged cell
    rowCurrent = rowCurrent + Cells(rowCurrent,1).MergeArea.Rows.Count
Wend
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9408817/9808063

Comment: @Naresh ?  "Centre Across Selection" is not available in Vertical.  The accepted answer on that question does not apply to this question, so (per StackOverflow guidelines) it is not a Duplicate, even if some of the comments *might*.

Comment: Yes.. Agreed .. The link is just for reference to the comments on that answer. by [Josh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341536/josh-brown)

Comment: This is a clever way to loop down both col **A** and **B** *(+1)*

Comment: Just because the accepted answer isn't the best in the linked thread, this is a dupe, as that thread (@Naresh's link, or better, https://stackoverflow.com/a/20365398/9245853) definitely proposes using `MergeArea.Cells(1, 1)`... still a valid answer here. This thread can serve as a pointer to that thread (which, with 133k views, is probably a good dupe target).

Comment: This loop is a better idea.. We can also determine if a cell is in merged area like this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22076713/9808063)